# Deploy web service application to network static IP address

Tags: c#, web-services, networking, tcp

I have created a *web service application* in Visual Studio. The Web service can be accessed by the following URL.

http://localhost:1863/WebServiceTest.asmx (when in Debug mode)
http://192.168.1.252/WebServiceApp/WebServiceTest.asmx (after publish through IIS)

The program still works if I replace "192.168.1.252" to the static IP address of the network. However, the same URL will not work if not using the same network - a *"Connection refused" error is returned.

How can I fix or debug this?

What I have done:

1. Added TCP port 80 in both the inbound and outbound rule using [Windows Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall) with *Advanced Security*.
2. Changed the PC to use a static IP address (192.168.1.252).
3. Forwarded port 80 to the static IP address (192.168.1.252) and port 80.
4. Turned off the firewall.
5. `netstat -a show port 0.0.0.0:80` is *Listening*.
6. telnet "network static IP address" "80" fail to connect.

Comment: Can you share server and client config?

Comment: 192.168.1.252 is (tipically) a local IP address, meaning local to your LAN. If this is the case, you obviously will not able to reach it from outside the LAN.
You will need to config your router in order to forward requests to the internal IP address (and port)

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Do you mean Web.config? If yes then please refer to below. I don't have client app.
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: @GianPaolo Port Forwarding in the router is not enough? My phone has IP 10.98.241.248, so I added a Port Forward with source target "10.98.241.248" of Port 80 to local IP (192.168.1.252) with port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You should set *:port* in IIS setting of your website:

IIS* → right click on your website* → click *Edit Binding* → on the form, select row → *edit* → change the port and then save.

Comment: My web service is under Default Web Site. So after I click Edit Binding, the Port is 80 and IP Address is *. 
Is this configuration correct? Or what should be changed? I suppose Port 80 is alright?